# Create a Game start menu using Python kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I want to create a game menu which is resizable and can be compatible with python and kivy. I created a button on a screen and when i resize it the button is not resized only screen is resized.

The button are not displaying. I want to create a GUI in which there is a Background image and a button is created on a the image and screen should be resizable.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.graphics import BorderImage
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
<style>:
    canvas.before:
    BorderImage:
        pos: self.pos
        size: self.size
        source: "round.png"
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            size: self.size
            Button:
                text:"Start Game"
                font_size: 100
                size: 100,50
                pos: 360,1024 
            Button:
                text:"Exit"
                font_size:100
                size: 100,50
                pos: 360,768
            Button:
                text:"About"
                font_size:100
                size:100,500
                pos: 360,512               


 ''')






class style(FloatLayout):
    pass

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return style()

if __name__=="__main__" :
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Comment: @JohnAnderson I have edited the post and added my piece of code.I request you to review my code and give me an explanation and proper advice on what should be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get resizable `Widgets`, the easiest way is to use `size_hint` rather than `size`. Then `Kivy` will adjust the sizes of things for you. Also, in order to get a background image, you can use `Rectangle` and provide an image as the `source`. Here is a modification of your code using the ideas I mentioned:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
<style>:
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: "round.png"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'top':1.0}
        size_hint: 0.25, 0.25
        Button:
            text:"Start Game"
        Button:
            text:"Exit"
        Button:
            text:"About"      
 ''')


class style(FloatLayout):
    pass


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return style()


if __name__=="__main__" :
    MyApp().run()
```

Using a `BoxLayout` does a lot of the work for you. It arranges your `Buttons` in a vertical stack (in your case), and assigns sizes to them to fill the `BoxLayout`. So, basically, you only need to worry about the size of the `BoxLayout`, and let it handle it's children. In the above code I have set `size_hint` to `0.25, 0.25`, but you can set it to whatever looks good. And then the `BoxLayout` is positioned setting `pos_hint` to `{'center_x': 0.5, 'top':1.0}`. This positions it in the center of the display horizontally, and at the top of the display. Again, you set it to whatever you want.

Note that there are no `size_hints` or `sizes` on the `Buttons`. That's because `BoxLayout` will handle those.

You had set `font_size` to `100` for the `Buttons`, which seems quite large to me,  so I just used the default `font_size`, which is `15sp` (the `sp` means that the size is scaled for the device being used). Unfortunately, there is no `size_hint` for `font_size`, so the text will remain constant size as the `Buttons` get scaled.

The main idea is to use hints whenever possible (instead of setting actual sizes and positions), so that `Kivy` can do the work for you.

Comment: Well First of all I would like to thank  you for your efforts.I am coming up with some doubts:  The size of rectangle is the size of the screen?. 2. How size_hint will work and pos_hint will work?(I am very confused about the hints in kivy)

Comment: I mean how these coordinates work...Like 0.5,1.0 as pos_hint

Comment: See the documentation for [pos_hint](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html?highlight=pos_hint#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.pos_hint) and [size_hint](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html?highlight=pos_hint#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.size_hint_x)